# How to dispose System.Windows.Media.Brushes

Tags: c#, winforms

i would like to ask how can i dispose the `System.Windows.Media.Brushes`. i think it consumes a lot of memory in my program.

i have tried to dispose the chart itself but the memory is still increasing in time.

```
monthlySeq1.Series.Add(
                new StackedColumnSeries
                {
                    Title = "Maintenance",
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { MtMS1D[1], MtMS1D[2], MtMS1D[3], MtMS1D[4], MtMS1D[5], MtMS1D[6], MtMS1D[7], MtMS1D[8], MtMS1D[9], MtMS1D[10], MtMS1D[11], MtMS1D[12], MtMS1D[13], MtMS1D[14], MtMS1D[15], MtMS1D[16], MtMS1D[17], MtMS1D[18], MtMS1D[19], MtMS1D[20], MtMS1D[21], MtMS1D[22], MtMS1D[23], MtMS1D[24], MtMS1D[25], MtMS1D[26], MtMS1D[27], MtMS1D[28], MtMS1D[29], MtMS1D[30], MtMS1D[31] },
                    StackMode = StackMode.Values,
                    ColumnPadding = 0.5,
                    Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.WhiteSmoke,
                    StrokeThickness = 0.7,
                    Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black
                });
```

is there a way on how i can dispose the System.Windows.Media.Brushes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look how it is used. From that you can see it is **static** class (well, at least it has static properties, which you use). You don't instantiate this class, thus you cannot dispose it.

Generally, what I do if I *suspect* the object should be disposed, I look at the Microsoft documentation to see, if it implements `IDisposable`. Or quicker way, if you use some IDE (eg. Visual Studio), I write `myObject.Dispose()` and see if it generates error, if not - object should be dispoed.

Finally, if you have disposable object, you can explicitly call `Dispose` on it or you can use `using` keyword (note that in new release of C#, 8.0, there is more convenient way of using `using`, [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations))

Comment: oh i understand. because i used it as a static so i cannot dispose.

Comment: System.Windows.Media.Brush MediumSeaGreen;
MediumSeaGreen = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.MediumSeaGreen); i will try this and try to dispose it. thank you